# Using System Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a general question that keeps coming to my mind. Is there any major disadvantage in using the SQL Server 2000 system tables in SQL Server 2008? It is a good practice to use system views, but in simple words, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BOL, [Catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> We recommend that you use catalog
>   views because they are the most
>   general interface to the catalog
>   metadata and provide the most
>   efficient way to obtain, transform,
>   and present customized forms of this
>   information. All user-available
>   catalog metadata is exposed through
>   catalog views.

The link also says catalog views will maintained across versions and hide the actual tables which can change. Going forward, these are the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Yes - they're deprecated and will be removed at some point in time.

If you get used to using the new `sys.` catalog views now, you won't have to do that later on when the old-style SQL Server 2000 system tables might be gone completely.

Also, in my opinion, it's much easier and more "focused" to

```
  select * from sys.foreign_keys
```

than to do something like

```
  select * from sysobjects where type = 'F'
```

The intent (selecting data about foreign keys) is more clearly stated, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Marc already said, I'd add that they are also not maintained and not brought up to date for new features, so you may be missing important information.